# Determining Whether Query Load is Too High for PostgreSQL Server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, ubuntu, postgresql-11, docker

I just started experiencing some write-heavy load on a PostgreSQL 11.2 system running inside a Docker container on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. PostgreSQL is receiving about 1-4k INSERT queries/second.

How can one determine whether this amount of load is too high for the system? Are there some metrics to monitor, like one that shows the number of queries being queued up at any one time?

---

**System Specs**

- Intel® Atom™ C2750 (8-Core, 2.4GHz)
- 8GB DDR3
- 240 GB SSD

**Output of `htop`**

2 node.js app concurrently sending queries to PostgreSQL. Both app and database are running on the same server.

[image]

**Output of `iotop`**

[image]

**Output of `iostat -c 5 999`**

[image]

**Output of `vmstat 1`**

[image]

**pgAdmin**

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as "too many queries". Does your application meet its SLA targets (response time, latency, TPS)? If so, then there's nothing to do. If not, identify the bottleneck and resolve it.

Comment: @mustaccio I'll like to know how to evaluate whether the server needs to be upgraded in the case where the load doubles or triples. I am unsure how to judge the response time in this case where the database is simply collecting time series data being sent to it (fire and forget) most of the time. The database data is then unloaded to a larger server every 2-3 days

Comment: postgresql does not appear to be the problem,  most of the sessions are sitting idle most of the time,  the IO wait is starting to get up there.   node.js seems to be the bottle neck sitting @ 65% and 36%

Comment: @zheep Thanks for the interpretation! Can you explain what does it mean by "IO wait is stating to get up there"? Are you referring to the `%iowait` values from `iostat`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx %IOWAIT is the amount of time system is waiting on the disk subsystem to complete a task as noted by Laurenz .  When this starts getting above 10% this starts cascading through the rest of the system where the all CPUs stop doing anything waiting on data to show up.  the magic number to upgrade on will change on the person you are talking to.  from a DB perspective we always want this low because we hit the IO harder than most loads..

Answer (score 1):

This is not a horrible load for modern server hardware.

On a write heavy DB its going to be dependent on the Hard-disk layer, triggers, functions, indexes and constraints that have to be processed/checked.

An easy way to get to the information you want is to install pgAdmin,  and use the dashboard to see what is going on. Number of connections, transactions per second, tuples in and out

From there need to study system load using,  some kind of System Monitor,  i like glances,  this will get the information on the CPU , Network and HD loads,

If there is significant wait times on the CPU or HD,  can adjust the [log settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) in postgresql.conf to record which queries take longer than X time

Comment: Don't forget to vote the question. If it's good enough to spend time answering surely it's good enough to up click?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have insert triggers that do complex stuff, an `INSERT` is probably bottlenecked by either CPU or I/O.

Use `vmstat 1` to determine what is the case: High CPU utilization is obvious, high I/O load manifests as `iowait%` at 10 or higher. This assumes that you have not set CPU or I/O limits on the container.

If both values look fine, you are probably not maxed out.